# Routes aren't rendered after upgrading to React Router 2.0

Tags: react-router

I'm trying to upgrade to 2.0 from version 0.13.x. This is my setup, and it's only working when the page is first loaded. The page transitions are handled by TurboLinks in Rails. I'm reloading the routes after the page is ready. I wonder if I'm doing something wrong...

```
$(() => {
  // Create the #RouterContainer
  if (!document.getElementById('RouterContainer')) {
    let el = document.createElement('div');
    el.setAttribute('id', 'RouterContainer');
    document.body.appendChild(el);
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<DocumentTitle title={ENV.title}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        { routes }
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </DocumentTitle>, document.getElementById('RouterContainer'));
});
```

Comment: as far as I know there is no React Router 0.14... do you mean 0.13.x? Can you provide more info on what actually happens? any errors? it's hard to help if you just say that it doesn't work...

Comment: Yes, I meant 0.13.x. There are no errors at all. The routes don't work if they are re-rendered when the new page is loaded via TurboLinks, but they do work the first time the page loads.

Comment: so the code above was working fine with the Router 0.13.x?